# Prove that the functor $P : \text{Set}^\text{op} → \text{Set}$ , $F(f)=f^{-1}:P(Y)\rightarrow P(X)$ for $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is representable

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

Let $P(A)$ denote the power set of a set $A$

For a map $f : X \mapsto Y$ of sets,  I can define a map $P( f ): P(Y) → P(X)$ s.t that I obtain a functor $P : \text{Set}^\text{op} \to \text{Set}$  in the following way:

$F(f)=f^{-1}:P(Y)\rightarrow P(X)$ for $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a set-theoretic map, where $f^{-1}$ is the preimage mapping.

$F(X)=P(X) , \forall X \in \text{Obj(Set)}$

**How can I prove that P is representable and find the representing object?**

So by definition of representability, I want to find and set $R$,

s.t. $h_R=\text{Hom}_\text{Set}(-,R)\cong P$

i.e. s.t. $h_R(X)=\text{Hom}_\text{Set}(X,R)\cong P(X)$, for all $X \in \text{Set}$

On the other hand  Yoneda lemma tells me that:

$\text{Hom}_\text{Set^}(h_X,P)\cong P(X)$, for all $X \in \text{Set}$

But I don't know how this helps. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It helps if you already know the answer, which is that $R=2$, the set with two elements

Comment: @ziggurism How do you come out with the anwer in the first place, can it be logically deduced stepwise?

Comment: I'm not sure about a rigorous step by step derivation, but one very big clue is to count cardinalities. The number of subsets of of $X$ is $2^{|X|}$, which you can deduce combinatorially by reasoning that for each element of the set, it is either included in the subset or not. A choice of true or false for each element of the set. Whereas the number of functions in $\text{hom}(X,R)$ is $|R|^{|X|}$. It's not much of a leap from there to $R=2=\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The first check you should do to see if a functor is representable is whether is preserves limits. Since $P : \mathsf{Set}^\text{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$, that means we want to show $P$ sends limits in $\mathsf{Set}^\text{op}$ to limits in $\mathsf{Set}$. That is, $P$ should send *colimits* in $\mathsf{Set}$ to limits in $\mathsf{Set}$.

As a special case of this fact, can you show $P(A \sqcup B) = P(A) \times P(B)$? That is, that the powerset of a disjoint union is (in natural bijection with) the product of the powersets?

This is some evidence that the functor is representable at all. But now, how do we go about finding the representing object? One way is to try and guess it directly. We want to write the powerset $P(X)$ as a homset $\mathsf{Set}(X,R)$ for a representing object $R$. Since sets are determined by their cardinality (up to isomorphism), let's do some examples and see if we can spot a pattern!

If $|X| = 0$, then $|P(X)| = 1$. If $|X| = 2$, then $|P(X)| = 2$. In general, you probably know that if $|X| = \alpha$ then $|P(X)| = 2^\alpha$. So, with this in mind, we want to find a set $R$ so that $|\text{Hom}(X,R)| = 2^{|X|}$. If you remember [some combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209361/number-of-distinct-functions-between-two-finite-sets), this says you should take $|R| = 2$.

Can you show that $R = \{ \top, \bot \}$ works as the representing object?

---

Another angle is to try and find a *universal element*. If $R$ represents $P$, then $\mathsf{Set}(R,R) \cong P(R)$ and the image of $\text{id}_R$ under this isomorphism is a *universal element* of $P$. Call it $\xi \in P(R)$. This means that *every element* of $P(X)$ is the preimage of $\xi$ under a unique map $f : X \to R$.

Said this way, we want to find a set with a distinguished subset, so that *every* subset is a preimage of this one. Since we know what the answer should be from the previous discussion, I'll say that the subset in question is $\{ \top \} \in P(\{\top, \bot\})$.

After all, if $A \in P(X)$ is any subset of $X$, then write $\mathbb{1}_A(x) = \begin{cases} \top & x \in A \\ \bot & x \not \in A \end{cases}$ for the indicator function of $A$. (Note $\mathbb{1}_A \in \mathsf{Set}(X, \{ \top, \bot \})$). It's not hard to see that $A = \mathbb{1}_A^{-1}( \{ \top \} )$ is the preimage of the universal subset under this map.

---

Lastly, you might ask about "automating" this process. Is there a way to always find the representing object given a representable functor? Eventually this kind of thing becomes "easy to see", after you've worked with enough exmaples, but in general it can be hard to explicitly get your hands on a representing object if you merely know that one exists. For instance, many [moduli spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_space) are defined as representing objects for certain functors, but investigating their geometry explicitly can be quite challenging. Ironically, this is one place where the category theory can be quite helpful, by giving a way to show that functors *are* representable without necessarily needing to find the representing object! See an old blog post of mine [here](https://grossack.site/2023/02/20/abstract-tensor-products) for more about that.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is supposed to be the follow-up to my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787843/let-f-x-mapsto-y-of-sets-how-can-i-define-a-map-p-f-py-%e2%86%92-px-s-t?noredirect=1#comment10178901_4787843.

Comment: There I follow the suggestion of defining the functor F as $F(f)=F^{-1}$ and proved that that yielded a functor from Set$^\text{op}$ to Set.  So was that definition not useful to prove the representability? or is it the same? ( Someone also suggested the two-element set thing but I didn't understand it or notice it was useful ) How do you define the action of P on morphisms then? I still have to prove P it is a functor with the appropiate definition that is useful in the representability proof

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to prove P is representable in the first place?.   This is the very first example I am seeing on how to do that.  If I understood that was independent of finding the representing object. Or is it proving that $R = \{ \top, \bot \}$ works as the representing object enought to prove the representability and find the representing object at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

On the specific question of how you could discover a candidate for a representing object without guessing:

Note that if we have an isomorphism of functors $P \simeq h_R$, then in particular we get a bijection $P(\{ * \}) \simeq h_R(\{ * \})$ where $\{ * \}$ is a one-element set.  On the other hand, $h_R(\{ * \}) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}^{op}}(R, \{ * \}) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(\{ * \}, R)$ is bijective to $R$.  Therefore, we would get $R$ bijective to $P(\{ * \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ * \} \}$.  In other words, the representing object $R$ must be some two-element set.

Once you have this information, you can then use Yoneda's lemma to observe that giving a morphism of functors $\alpha : h_\Omega \to P$ is equivalent to giving an element $\Omega_0 \in P(\Omega)$ where we set $\Omega$ to be the particular two-element set $\{ true, false \}$.  Furthermore, the proof of Yoneda's lemma gives that once you have chosen the element $\Omega_0$, the corresponding functor $\alpha : h_\Omega \to P$ is given by $\alpha_X : h_\Omega(X) \to P(X)$, $f \in h_\Omega(X) = \operatorname{Hom}(X, \Omega) \mapsto f^{-1}(\Omega_0)$.  Finally, you know that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of functors if and only if $\alpha_X$ is an isomorphism in $\mathsf{Set}$ for each object $X$.

So, at this point, you are left with simply checking which of the possible choices $\Omega_0 \in P(\Omega)$ satisfy that $f \mapsto f^{-1}(\Omega_0)$ is a bijection $\operatorname{Hom}(X, \Omega) \simeq P(X)$ for each set $X$.  It turns out that exactly $\Omega_0 := \{ true \}$ and $\Omega_0 := \{ false \}$ work; it turns out it is more customary to set $\Omega_0 := \{ true \}$.

Comment: Are proving representability and proving that the candidate is the representing object two things that are done separatelly or just proving the isomophism takes care of both at the same time? I am asking becaise one the answers seem to imply they were separte things. That it was possible to "show that functors are representable without necessarily needing to find the representing objec"

Comment: By definition, representability is the same thing as "there exists $R$ such that $R$ is a representing object".  So, if you prove that some object is a representing object for the functor $P$, then you've also proved that $P$ is representable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to prove the representability? The partial answers I got are not helping , I've been stuck for hours. Does it amount to just proving that the commutative diagram in Mockingbird's answer commute? I am not sure though how to come up with the fact the isomorphism is given by the characteristic function (is this another guess?)and why do I need to find its inverse. How can a characteristic function have an inverse in the first place, if it maps just to 0 and 1, each preimage surelly has more than one element

Comment: Yes, showing that the diagram in Mockingbird's answer commutes is part of the definition of a morphism of functors.  (And then, once you know that you have a morphism $\alpha$ of functors, and $\alpha_X$ is an isomorphism for every object $X$, you can conclude that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of functors.)

Comment: Alternately, you can use Yoneda's lemma to show that giving a morphism of functors $h_\Omega \to P$ is equivalent to giving an element of $P(\Omega)$.  That gives you only four candidates for an isomorphism of functors (and the proof of Yoneda's lemma will tell you what those morphisms actually are); and from there, it would be a matter of checking which ones of those morphisms actually give an isomorphism.

Comment: In Mockingbird's anwer what is the expression for the horizontal arrows? Is it the inverse of the characteristic function? I can't even write compositions of the commutative diagram tha I need to check because I can't find the inverse

Comment: a subset is a declaration for each element of the set whether it is true or false that it is contained in the subset. That is the horizontal map of the commutative diagram. It turns a subset into the true false declaration map. the function given by f(x) = true iff x is in the subset. what is the inverse?

Comment: The inverse sends a function $f : X \to \Omega$ to the subset of $X$ given by $\{ x \in X \mid f(x) = true \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2=\{0,1\}$, the two-element set. The claim is that $P$ is represented by $2$. We need to prove that there is a natural isomorphism $P  \Rightarrow \mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(-,2) $. This isomorphism is defined by the correspondence that maps a subset $Y$ of $X$ to its characteristic function $\chi_Y: X \to 2$. (Try to find its inverse). Naturality means that for any function $f: X \to A$, if $\chi_B$ is the characteristic function of $B \subseteq A$, then $\chi_B \circ f$ is the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq X$, that is that the following commutes:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P(A) @>{}>> \mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(A,2) \\
@V {f^{-1}} VV @VV{- \circ f }V \\
P(X) @>>{}> \mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}}(X,2)
\end{CD}
$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: This question is a follow -up from my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787843/let-f-x-mapsto-y-of-sets-how-can-i-define-a-map-p-f-py-%e2%86%92-px-s-t?noredirect=1#comment10178901_4787843

Comment: But it looks like what I did there following the suggestion was not useful for this? I mean defining the functor on morphism as the preimage?

Comment: Some help with the inverse please?

Comment: the previous diagram worked anyway right?

Comment: Yes, since the horizontal arrows are isomorphisms, it doesn't matter if you put this arrow or the other (its inverse)